# Image blurred when container attached to mouse location

Tags: swift, nswindow, nsimageview, swift5

Im trying create magnify view but have some problems that can't understand.
I have `NSWindow` that contains `NSImageView`. When I set static origin point position to window, and moving only cursor (mouse), all captured fine. But when I set origin point to window from mouse location, image is huge blurred.

In image.addRepresentation(bitmap) I receiving normal image as I expected (that's was checked on debugger). Also in debug mode I saw that captured image fast zoomed from normal to huge when mouse moving.

Any suggestions?

NSWindow:

```
class ColorPickerWindow: NSWindow {

    private let colorPickerMagnifier: ColorPickerMagnifier!

    override init(contentRect: NSRect, styleMask style: NSWindow.StyleMask, backing backingStoreType: NSWindow.BackingStoreType, defer flag: Bool) {

        self.colorPickerMagnifier = ColorPickerMagnifier()
        let location = NSEvent.mouseLocation

        super.init(contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 120, height: 120),
                   styleMask: [],
                   backing: .buffered,
                   defer: true)

        self.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.level = .floating + 1000
        self.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
        self.isMovableByWindowBackground = false
        self.isOpaque = false
        self.hasShadow = false

        NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: .mouseMoved) { (event) -> NSEvent in

            let location = NSEvent.mouseLocation
            self.updatePickerLocation(location: location)
            print(location)

            return event
        }

        self.colorPickerMagnifier.frame = self.contentView!.bounds
        self.contentView?.addSubview(self.colorPickerMagnifier)        
        self.updatePickerLocation(location: location)
    }

    // MARK: - Private

    private func updatePickerLocation(location: CGPoint) {
        self.updatePickerImage(from: location)
        self.setFrameOrigin(NSPoint(x: location.x - self.contentView!.frame.width / 2, y: location.y - self.contentView!.frame.height / 2))
    }

    private func updatePickerImage(from location: CGPoint) {

        let magnifySize = CGFloat(8)
        let x = floor(location.x) - floor(magnifySize / 2)
        let y = (NSScreen.main?.frame)!.size.height - floor(location.y) - floor(magnifySize / 2)
        let captureRect = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: magnifySize, height: magnifySize)

        guard let cgImageFromScreen = CGWindowListCreateImage(captureRect, .optionOnScreenAboveWindow, .zero, .bestResolution) else {
            return
        }

        let bitmap = NSBitmapImageRep(cgImage: cgImageFromScreen)
        let image = NSImage()
        image.addRepresentation(bitmap)
        self.colorPickerMagnifier.image = image
    }
}
```

NSImageView:

```
class ColorPickerMagnifier: ImageViewDeInterpolated {

    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)

        self.imageScaling = .scaleProportionallyUpOrDown
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)
    }
}
```

Content when moving only mouse
[image: Content when moving only mouse]

Content when container attached to mouse position
[image: Content when container attached to mouse position]

Comment: Is the magnifier window included in the image?

Comment: NSImageView added to NSWindow as subview self.contentView?.addSubview(self.colorPickerMagnifier)

Comment: Are you magnifying the magnified image?

Comment: Yes. As I understood when View has static location, you getting data under cursor (normal data). But if View move to cursor location, cursor can't get data from screen, only from View. Im tried cut hole in center of View. But this does not help.

Comment: Is the magnifier window a window or a view? Did you try to create an image of the windows below the magnifier window?

Comment: @Willeke, I found source file Magnifier on swift. Added to project. Thanks for helping